# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager: change column width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a RecyclerView and a GridLayoutManager.
The columns width are equal but I want the first column with `80dp` width.
Is this possible?

> Example: RecyclerView width 5 columns

```
final columnsCount = 5;

recyclerView.width = 500dp

column0.width = 80dp

column 1-2-3-4 width = (recyclerview.width - column0.width) / columnsCount
```

[image]

Any advice?

Edit: code

```
public class TestRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_START = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_PROGRESS_ITEM = 1;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public TestRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_START;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_PROGRESS_ITEM;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view;
        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_START:
                view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_item_small, parent, false);
                return new TestViewHolder(view);
            case VIEW_TYPE_PROGRESS_ITEM:
                view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_item, parent, false);
                return new TestViewHolder(view);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

view_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0000FF"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

view_item_small.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF0000"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Usage:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new TestRecyclerViewAdapter(this));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 5));
}
```

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: Does the solution(I assume it is, may be wrong) provided in your edit really work? I set fixed width in the columns xml but there is no effect.

Comment: @Ixx No the edit is my code demonstrating my issue, not the solution sadly.

Answer (score 0):

in your adapter you can do that.

check if the item's position equals 0, if so then inflate the layout with 80dp width.

Comment: While this answers part of the question ("Is this possible?"), you really should explain how to set the column width or just leave a comment instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second layout with a 80dp width to use in your `RecyclerView.Adapter`, then in the `onCreateViewHolder()` method check if the item's position equals 0, if so then inflate the layout with 80dp width, else inflate the normal layout. 
You should create your own viewTypes to do so, you will have to override the `getItemViewType(int position)` method for that, this will look something like this:

```
private static final int VIEWTYPE_FIRST_ITEM = 1;
private static final int VIEWTYPE_NORMAL_ITEM = 2;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position == 0) {
        return VIEWTYPE_FIRST_ITEM;
    } else {
        return VIEWTYPE_NORMAL_ITEM;
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    if(viewType == VIEWTYPE_FIRST_ITEM) {
        view =  //TODO inflate layout with 80dp
    } else {
        view =  //TODO inflate normal layout
    }
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

Comment: I inflate the layout in onCreateViewHolder(), not in onBindViewHolder()

Comment: yea sorry my mistake, that should be onCreateViewHolder(), I will edit the answer